# get data json file for angular js app-in-app in grails directly

Tags: javascript, grails, angularjs

hi i want to access my json data file in my angular app inside an app  in grails. i dont find any way to address the json file clientside. in the tutorial the databinding is only cocered for json data so this is crucial for me.

```
function ShitCtrl($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('http://localhost:8080/webapp/clients.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.shits = data;
  });
}


function ShitDetailCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.shitId = $routeParams.shitId;

}
```

this reports an 404 error. how can i solve this issue? when i address it in urlMappings
this does not work then the mappings are absolute.

the point is: grails maps everything based on urlMappings, so it is not possible to address a file directly from js.

Comment: +1 for using my variable naming convention.

Comment: The JS code looks okay. Have you tried just browsing to the file directly with a browser?

Comment: yeah, well the js is good, just the grails framework does not like direct linkings into somewhere the app, so  an additional resources folder in Config.Groovy with access for all was the breakthrough for solving this. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config . groovy:

```
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = [
        '/images/*',
        '/css/*',
        '/js/*',
        '/plugins/*',
        **'/staticData/*',**
        '/assets/*'
```

so this then works like a charm:

```
function ShitCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('../static/staticData/clients.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.shits = data;
  });
}
```